# Input fails if not used in ngfor

Tags: angular, ngfor

Why this works `<page *ngFor="let page of pages" [page]="page"></page>` and this doesn't `<page [page]="pages[0]"></page>`?
If I always have at least one element in array sholdn't be the same output? In the first case it works, but in the second I get `undefined` value for `page`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to make sure that `pages` exist and not empty:

```
<page *ngIf="pages?.length" [page]="pages[0]" ></page>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on initial value of `pages` if the initial value is null and then you fill the values, for a short amount of time `pages[0]` is undefined, and if there is javascript error then it break and even when there is value in pages bindings doesn't work

To check if it's your case try this

```
<page [page]="pages[0]" *ngIf="pages && pages.length"></page>
```